# Can't start Matlab on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, matlab

I've downloaded and installed Matlab 2018b in a folder named Matlab in

```
/home/user/Matlab
```

the file I want to run is

```
/home/user/Matlab/bin/matlab
```

where `matlab` is a shell script application. First I place myself in the bin folder

```
cd /home/user/Matlab/bin
```

and then I want to run it by

```
./matlab
```

I get the following error messages:

```
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
/home/user/Matlab/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/user/Matlab/bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so)
/home/user/Matlab/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/user/Matlab/bin/glnxa64/libmwmst.so)
/home/user/Matlab/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/user/Matlab/bin/glnxa64/libCppMicroServices.so.3.3.1)
```

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Comment: Install other(newer) version of libstdc++6, which supports GLIBCXX_3.4.22.

Comment: I just moved to linux from windows yesterday so I'm not so sharp at this atm. But can I enter a command in the terminal to do this or should I google for that file online, download it and run the installer? (normal windows proceedure).

Comment: This did not solve my problem. I did what was outlined here: https://altlinux.pkgs.org/sisyphus/classic-i586/libstdc++6-7.3.1-alt5.i586.rpm.html

Comment: altlinux is a different distribution than ubuntu. Use ubuntu packages on ubuntu. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libstdc%2B%2B6&searchon=names

Comment: So I get to this site: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libstdc++6. How do I know which one to choose?

Comment: If you're very noob in linux, install the latest ubuntu ([18.10](http://ftp.freepark.org/pub/CDROM-Images/ubuntu/18.10/)) or debian [stable](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-cd/) instead of manually upgrading packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install the missing required files first.

    sudo apt-get install libstdc++6

If that does not work:

    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 

    sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get upgrade

    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

If that does not work post error msg's again as some thing new may be seen as missing.